# Subfigures in Quarto (pdf)

Tags: r, quarto

I was trying to insert multiple figures (subplots) in Quarto for the `pdf` output. I'm not generating plots in the code but importing `.png` files to generate the figure.

I tried in 2 ways, but it wasn't successful. Is there a way to achieve this in Quarto?

Below are my unsuccessful examples:

1. Using `knitr::include_graphics`

```
#| label: myplot2
#| layout: [[1,1],[1,1]]
#| out-width: "250px"
#| fig-show: "hold"
#| fig-cap: Myplot
#| fig-subcap: 
#|   - "a"
#|   - "b"
#|   - "c"
#|   - "d"
#| echo: false
#| warning: false
#| message: false
knitr::include_graphics(c(fig1, fig2, fig3, fig4))
```

Above example generates 4 plots, but each plots are recognized as figure, not subfigures.

```
#| label: myplot2
#| layout: [[1,1],[1,1]]
#| out-width: "250px"
#| fig-show: "hold"
#| fig-cap: Myplot
#| fig-subcap: 
#|   - "a"
#|   - "b"
#|   - "c"
#|   - "d"
#| echo: false
#| warning: false
#| message: false
knitr::include_graphics(fig1)
knitr::include_graphics(fig2)
knitr::include_graphics(fig3)
knitr::include_graphics(fig4)
```

This method does not generate 4 figures, but only 1.

2. Using `div`

```
::: {#fig-subplots layout="[[1,1],[1,1]]"}

![a](fig1.png)
![b](fig2.png)
![c](fig3.png)
![d](fig4.png)

Myplot
:::
```

It also generates a plot 2 by 2, and it is the closet to the solution, but it does not generate subcaptions for each subplot.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have the plots already created and only want to include the PNG images, you can use the figure directive.

```
::: {#fig-myplot layout-ncol=2}

![a](fig1.png)

![b](fig2.png)

![c](fig3.png)

![d](fig4.png)

Myplot
:::
```

More details at https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/figures.html.